# My server will not connect to my router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have been trying to set up a Minecraft server for a while now, After completing all the steps it doesn't work, I tested Minecraft on the server-computer and I was able to join the server, I tried on another computer on my LAN, and it didn't work, needless to say my friends can't join does anyone have suggestions on why its not working?
I tried fixing port forwarding until I found that wasn't the problem.

Internet setup: Spectrum>arris sb6141>AirPort Extreme

Note: I have no idea which ip is which, so for testing I continue to use all of them.

Comment: From a LAN computer, you need to connect to the LAN IP. If that doesn't work, then there's a firewall blocking the connection. To find out the correct ip, on the server, do ipconfig /all in a cmd window (or ifconfig if it is linux).

Comment: I would try using `nmap` to test if that port of server is available and it's not filtered, if it's filtered, then you need to allow connections to that port from outside, if it shows `open`, so no filtered or closed, then it would be some routing error, but on LAN it should work, in this case `ping`ing that server would reveal some information